# Why are my LED bulbs flashing?

Tags: led, dimmer-switch

I recently replaced all eight bulbs on my chandeleir with dimmable led light bulbs.  They work fine when on, but at approximately half power (dimmer turned half way through), the bulbs start flashing (high and low light) in an alternate manner.  This continues even at high / full power.  When I tried removing one bulb, the frequency increases.  When I removed two bulbs, the frequency returns as with 8 bulbs.  Any help / advice pls?  Thanks!

Comment: Is your dimmer compatible with LED bulbs? Are your LED bulbs rated as dimmable?

Comment: This is because you have the chandelier on Christmas mode. You need to switch it back to regular mode.

Answer (score 3):

Either because your dimmer is not rated for LEDs or your bulbs have a defect.

You have to understand that each LED now has in essence its own motherboard that controls how the LED bulbs are functioning, the dimmable ones being much more complex.  A lot manufacturers are still on their first generation of dimmables too.  They just aren't "programmed" to be used for all instances.  Whether it be the output the dimmer is giving, the way it gives it, other interference on the circuit, and so on.  Very good friend of mine manages at Lowe's and said that by far the #1 return in their store is dimmable LEDs.

So what can you do?

- Make sure that your dimmer is rated for LEDs.
- adjust the dimming settings on your dimmer
- Try a different brand of LEDs.
- Try a different style
- Try a different wattage

I have track lighting above my stairs leading to basement.  Took me 4 different LED bulbs to find one that would appropriate dim without issues.  One never really dimmed (maybe got to 60-70%), one blinked like yours, and the other one only came on when the dimmer was turned at least halfway up - and when you got to 90% on the dimmer they turned off.

I would say that in almost all of these cases there is nothing wrong with your setup it is just that the technology isn't ready for the new energy consumption regulations.  Dimming bulbs became very en vogue 15-20 years ago to save energy.  Some states required dimmers for incandescent outlets...  When LEDs first came out the manufacturers weren't worried about dimmers/energy savings since their bulbs would beat out the most dimmed incandescent.

Answer (score 0):

not all dimmable led are compatible with the existing dimmer switches in you home .
your dimmer and light works OK , with your halogen or incandescent bulb but not when you change all bulbs to led . 
because the old dimmer are  sensitive to at least 40 or 50 watts ( with a resistence of xxxx ohms ). 
the led light are not resistive , so it start to flash when you dim down 50% .
the solution , you keep one halogen , or incandescent in the circuit ( with every dimmer )  and all will work prefect .
for example if your dimmer control a chandelier of 20 bulbs , you can replace 19 to led and keep 1 bulb incancescent .

sometimes if you replace all bulbs in a chandelier , you may experience , that light cannot be shut off , or cannot put on ,,,

also same solution , keep one conventional bulb and all will work normally and dim completely 
Moises 
Panama